# Providing Access-Control-Allow-Origin with a Wildcard

Tags: php, ajax, same-origin-policy, access-control

I am making a page that responds to an AJAX request with a certain string when another certain string is provided as a GET variable. In order to avoid problems with the "same origin" policy, I have found that I can include this line of PHP at the top of the page:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

There's no sensitive data being passed whatsoever, it's actually keywords passed back and forth from several different domains, (its an SEO related application). Due to this, hundreds of different domains will be using it, so if possible I would like to avoid specifying each one. Are there any risks to using this line? If so, what are they?

Also, if this page was located under an HTTPS URL is it still accessible?

Any advice, suggestions or concerns are most welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the access truly is public, I'd say this is a good solution.  However, if you want to limit the access to your site, you'll probably want to list explicitly each domain origin allowed.

Since you say your response doesn't include any sensitive information, you probably don't need to worry about hosting your service over HTTPS.  The one reason you might is if a client HTTPS page tries to access your non-HTTPS service.  In that case, I would guess they'd get a warning about unsecure information being sent/received when your AJAX service is called, and maybe even just a silent fail.  If this is a common enough case, then I'd say looking into the HTTPS service.  Make sure your HTTPS certificate is certified properly, because if the client's browser cannot verify the certificate the AJAX request will silently fail (as opposed to prompting when you navigate directly to an HTTPS page)!  Also, I don't know how it will go in your case, but whenever I've worked with HTTPS, I've usually had to tweak things to get them to function properly.

Long story short, I'd start with HTTP and then evaluate the need of HTTPS.  Good luck!

Comment: @Pete Herbert Penito Welcome :)